# az cli login using the wrong account

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I hvae got 2 azure accounts, one is personal and the other is for work. what happens sometimes is that I want to test out code on my personal account first rather than work, I do however need to switch az cli between the 2 accounts. To make the process less painful, I have written the snippet below.

login.ps1

```
az account clear

# Select the tenant ID:
az login --tenant xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

# Set a validated subscription:
az account set --subscription "subscription name"
```

After running the above on PowerShell terminal within windows 10, I do get a login prompt on the browser which gets me to login to my work azure subscription, it can see that i am still logged in, it confirms this however to my suprise I am still logged onto my personal azure subscription. when I run the command `get-azresourcegroup` I still get a list of resource groups relating to my personal subscription. I have the following questions.

1. What do I need to do in order to switch over to my work
   subscription.
2. What is wrong with my snippet of code above, and why is it not
   working ?

Comment: There is a cookie that is remembering the last login.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-authentication-web-browser-cookies

Answer (score 0):

To **get the user account connected with the Azure CLI,** make use of below command:

```bash
az account show
```

And to clear the account connected, use `az account clear`.

[image]

**To switch between the accounts**, I used the same script:

```bash
az account clear
az login --tenant TenantID
az account set --subscription "SubscriptionName"
```

I connected to Azure CLI using **`User1`** account:

[image]

Now, I am trying to **switch account to** **`User2`** account:

[image]

[image]

***I am able to switch user accounts successfully and you are using the correct script to do it.***

> When I run the command `get-azresourcegroup` I still get a list of resource groups relating to my personal subscription.

**Note** that:  `Get-AzResourceGroup` command uses `Connect-AzAccount`not `az login`.

When you connect `az login` with your work account and getting resource groups relating to your personal subscription using `Get-AzResourceGroup` that means you are using personal account to connect with `Connect-AzAccount` .

To **fetch resource group using Azure CLI**, make use of below command:

```bash
az group list
```

I connected with **User2 account and got the resource groups of User2 subscription**:

[image]

To **Disconnect with Az account** use below command:

```bash
Disconnect-AzAccount
```

[image]

**References:**

[az group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group?view=azure-cli-latest)

[Get-AzResourceGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroup?view=azps-10.0.0)